# Pass only one argument to main() in C

Tags: c, gcc, program-entry-point

I ran this program in GCC(gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)) on Linux. It successfully compiled using `gcc myprog.c` and run without any warnings or errors.

So, **Why doesn't the compiler give any warnings or errors when only one argument is provided for `main` in C?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: I think parameters are not passed this way :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GCC 6 (on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64) my compiler does give some warning when compiling with `gcc -Wall rsp.c -o rsp` your `rsp.c` example.

```
rsp.c:3:5: warning: ‘main’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
 int main(int i)
     ^~~~
```

But the C11 programming language (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not specify when a compiler should warn. It mostly defines what are the *correct* possible programs and how should they behave. Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (I guess, but I am not sure, that you have one).

If you want to really understand what is actually happening in your case on your computer, study the source code of your compiler, the emitted assembler code (compile with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O rsp.c` then look into the generated `rsp.s`), the source code of your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), of your [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) runtime. Study also the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) relevant to your system.

I think you should be very scared of undefined behavior. Very [bad things could happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

As a practical advice when coding on Linux, **always compile with `-Wall` and `-g` passed to `gcc`**
The `-Wall` option asks for nearly all warnings (and you could add `-Wextra`). The `-g` option asks for debug information. You'll then be able to use the `gdb`  debugger to understand more what is happening at runtime.

Once you are confident in your code and have debugged it, consider compiling it with `-O` or `-O2` to ask for [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (in particular for benchmarking). (BTW, `gcc` can accept both `-g` and `-O2`). Read documentation on [GCC command options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Comment: Did you pass `-Wall` when compiling? And you really should upgrade your compiler (and probably even your entire Linux distribution)

Comment: That is practically a huge mistake. You should **change your compiling habits.**

Answer (score 4):

As per the C standard

#### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; **or in some other implementation-defined manner**.

If an implementation defines it to accept a single parameter, then it can.

Comment: Historically, the definition `int main(int i)` should be OK. `i` will just be the number of program arguments and `argv[]` will be inaccessible.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I am not sure of that. I agree with you that *practically* it should often work. But I don't feel that is OK (it is UB).

Comment: The definition of main in ISO 9899 only applies to hosted implementations. Freestanding implementations are free to define any startup function with any parameterization.

There have probably been conforming hosted implementations which would fail at runtime with `int main(int i)`. It's possible ILE C for the AS/400 would have, for example. The real lesson here is "learn the language you're using".

Comment: @MichaelWojcik A bit off-topic: I've read a little about the idiosyncrasies of the AS/400 and its ILE C. I can't think of what would cause `int main(int i)` to fail though, Care to elaborate?

Comment: @a3f I'm not sure it would - I only mentioned it because it's fairly strict, in part because of the capability architecture of the '400 (aka System i, etc). The ILE docs imply that the system is aware of omitted parameters, even for the PEP invocation of the main() UEP, and specify the allowed forms of main(); so it might detect this and raise a program check. Actually the older AS/400 C implementations, System/C and prior to that EPM C, might be more likely to object, but I don't remember how closely they conformed to the standard.