# What happens with one argument in main()?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

For the following program, some compilers execute it with a warning

> ```
> 3:5: warning: 'int main(int)' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
> ```

and some without any. Can I use main() with one argument?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int x)
{
   x = 5;
   std::cout << x;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not playing the game.

Comment: The C++ standard specifies the arguments to the `main` function. A single `int` argument is not among the valid alternatives. See e.g. [this `main` function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) for more information.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Not among the required alternatives, but still valid if the implementation supports it (source: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2)

Comment: "What happens with one argument in main()?" Implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Did you get a ***warning*** or an ***error***?   You got a *warning*, which means you can continue, but your code is definitely doing something unusual.

Comment: Is there any specific need, reason, justification, motivation,  incentive or reward for breaking the standard rule?

Comment: @A.S.H, It's very common to allow a third parameter for environment variables.

Comment: @ abelenky, I got warning. I learned from you that I can use main() with one argument but doing something unusual.

Comment: @chris that's allowed by the standard (form (3) in the link posted by SPD), but one and only one parameter isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass only one argument to main() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470292/pass-only-one-argument-to-main-in-c)

Comment: @ A.S.H., reason is that I am just learning C++ and explore it.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou I understand that, curiosity is a must in the learning process. But I wanted to say that I failed to find any use-cases. :)

Comment: @rsp: That's a C question. This one is about C++.

Comment: @A.S.H, The page is a bit misleading. From the current standard draft: *This function shall not be overloaded. Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.*

Comment: @chris Thanks. This is getting really really confusing. Reminds me someone said the "nice thing with standards is that you have so many to chose from". Same for so-called "references" I guess...

Comment: @A.S.H, In reality, it's probably written like that because there's no implementation I know of that allows one parameter, but there are plenty that allow 3.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard §3.6.1/2 says the following about the `main`
function:

> It shall have a return type of
>   type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All
>   implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of
>   `main`:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```

So it's ultimately up to your compiler to decide whether `int main(int x)` is OK or not. It goes without saying that using such a `main` function makes your code non-portable.

Comment: @ Christian Hackl, To me, a beginner in C++, it seems that as many C++ compilers as many C++s. By the way, what argc, char*, and argv mean? I know that in main()'s body I can write not only comments but many more, including variable definitions, statements, function calls.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou: We cannot teach you C++ like that. You need a good book which explains such basic things.

Comment: @  Christian Hackl: Do you suggest me one on-line?

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou: Yes! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @  Christian Hackl: Many thanks for suggestion. I chosen "C++ Primer".